# JPA - Is it possible to add a new persistable field to a class without updating the XML configuration file?

Tags: xml, jpa, openjpa, ddl, multiple-columns

I'm new to JPA. I wanted to know if there is any way to modify the xml of a class without actually making changes to it. That is add a new column to a table after the xml has been created?

Answer (score 0):

You xml tells JPA how it should map your class to the database. So if you want to modify your class and propagate your changements to the database, you must update your xml first.

If this behavior is too complicate, you can rely on **annotations** to speed up things. Simply, you modify your class, add an annotation and you are ready to play.

Example :

```
@Entity
class MyDomainObject {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String someField;

    // Constructor ...

    // getters and setters ...

    // Other methods ....
}
```

Later suppose you want to add another non nullable field. You would do:

```
@Entity
class MyDomainObject {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String someField;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String anotherField;

    // Constructor ...

    // getters and setters ...

    // Other methods ....
}
```

You have just modified your code and there is no headcache with an external xml file.

Comment: thanks. but what if I want to make this generic? like add an extra coloumn for every class i.e. write a method that adds an extra coloumn to every class that calls the method ?